# Problems storing data from csv in dictionary in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I’m creating a system to keep track of the performance of stocks over an extended period. What I intend for it to do is take tickers from a spreadsheet, search for those tickers on Yahoo finance, pull the historical data for those stocks and then stores the data against the ticker as dictionary or list. While I’ve got the webscrape working fine as well as attaching of the data against the ticker, I’m struggling to save the data within the for loop so I can access it later.

Here is the contents of spreadsheet:

```
Ticker    Name
WMT       Walmart
AMZN      Amazon
AAPL      Apple
CVS       CVS Health
```

After putting the contents of the sheet into a variable, I created the following series:

```
p_ticker = p_data['Ticker']
```

I have then set up a loop that runs through the sheet and applies the ticker from correctly.

```
for ticker in p_ticker:
    scrape_string = f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1=1480636740&period2=1606867140&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"
    ticker_data = {ticker:scrape_string}
    print(ticker_data)
```

However, for loops, dictionaries and lists are not particular areas of expertise and I would appreciate any advice available.

I’ve attempted the following:

```
for ticker in p_ticker:
    scrape_string = f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1=1480636740&period2=1606867140&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"
    ticker_data = []
    ticker_data.append = pd.read_csv(ticker)
```

This leads to an error saying: “FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File WMT does not exist: ‘WMT’”

If I try this:

```
for ticker in p_ticker:
    scrape_string = f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1=1480636740&period2=1606867140&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"
    ticker_data = []
    ticker_data.append = pd.read_csv(scrape_string)
```

I get `AttributeError: ‘list’ object attribute ‘append’ is read-only`

Unfortunately I'm a little bit stumped on how to take this forward; if anyone's got any ideas it would be of great help and I would be very grateful.

Comment: If you're using pandas, why do you need a dictionary as well?

Comment: Append is a function, you call it with `()`, you don't assign with `=`.

Comment: `ticker_data.append(something)`

Comment: You need to move the initialization `ticker_data = []` out of the loop. Otherwise you throw away all the previous iterations.

Comment: I think this data format is not going to be as you intend. If you can get the data as-needed, why store it? I'd make a function that takes in a ticker, start date, and end date and returns the result of the query.

Answer (score 1):

you need to move the dictionary outside of the loop like this:

```
ticker_data={}
for ticker in p_ticker:
    scrape_string =f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1=1480636740&period2=1606867140&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"
    ticker_data[ticker]=scrape_string
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty simple solution that uses a function that returns a combined DataFrame from all the tickers within the date range provided:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def get_quotes(tickers: list[str],
               start_date: datetime,
               end_date: datetime = datetime.now(),
               interval: str = '1d') -> pd.DataFrame:
    dfs: list[pd.DataFrame] = []    # initialize an empty list to store dataframes
    for ticker in tickers:          # loop over each ticker
        url = f'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1={int(start_date.timestamp())}&period2={int(end_date.timestamp())}&interval={interval}&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true'
        df = pd.read_csv(url)       # read the csv from the url into a pandas DataFrame
        df['ticker'] = ticker       # set the ticker value of each row to the current ticker
        dfs.append(df)              # append the DataFrame to the list of DataFrames
    return pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True) # combine the dataframes and reset the index for convenience

data = get_quotes(tickers=['aapl', 'msft'],
                  start_date=datetime.fromisoformat('2021-05-17'),
                  end_date=datetime.fromisoformat('2021-05-21T23:59')) # the end_date is optional, will default to current date

print(data)
```

Output:

```
         Date        Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close    Volume ticker
0  2021-05-17  126.820000  126.930000  125.169998  126.269997  126.269997  74244600   aapl
1  2021-05-18  126.559998  126.989998  124.779999  124.849998  124.849998  63342900   aapl
2  2021-05-19  123.160004  124.919998  122.860001  124.690002  124.690002  92612000   aapl
3  2021-05-20  125.230003  127.720001  125.099998  127.309998  127.309998  76857100   aapl
4  2021-05-21  127.820000  128.000000  125.209999  125.430000  125.430000  79209300   aapl
5  2021-05-17  246.550003  246.589996  243.520004  245.179993  244.615158  24970200   msft
6  2021-05-18  246.270004  246.410004  242.899994  243.080002  242.520004  20168000   msft
7  2021-05-19  239.309998  243.229996  238.600006  243.119995  243.119995  25739800   msft
8  2021-05-20  243.960007  247.949997  243.860001  246.479996  246.479996  21800700   msft
9  2021-05-21  247.570007  248.330002  244.740005  245.169998  245.169998  21855500   msft
```

This migh tbe improved by using a generator instead of a for loop `pd.concat()` those. Also, the end date should be set to either the end of the desired end date or the beginning of the next one because of how the Yahoo API works.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, I had a play around with your code however every time I ran it I got a "object is not subscriptable" on the interval line...

Comment: hmm, what code did you modify to produce that error? and what version of python